# Update view model after updating data from a jQuery .dialog using a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery-events

I have a MVC 4 view with multiple "detail" partial views, each of which have their own "edit" partial view that opens in a `jQuery.dialog`, with Save and Cancel buttons.  The "edit" partial views have a `@using (Ajax.BeginForm...)` tag that successfully submits the data to the controller after a user clicks Save on the .dialog.  The updated data is then handled with the `OnSuccess` event at which time I rebuild the affected table body and then tbody.replaceWith to update the "detail" partial view.

It just seems that with all that MVC 4 offers there should be an easier way to take the updated data from the controller, and reload just the updated partial view on the original view.  Is there anything better than all the Javascript and jQuery code like the following, which is an example of the first "detail" partial view on the original view?  And, continue to use the `jQuery.dialog/partial` view.

```
@model Models.DemographicsViewModel
@using System.Web.Helpers
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
<p>
    <button class="showModal" id="ShowDemographicsEdit" name="ShowDemographicsEdit" onclick="OpenDemographicsEdit(@Model.Demographic.PK_DemographicsID);">Edit</button>
</p>
<div id="DemographicsMessage"></div>

<div id="DemographicsList">
    <table id="DemographicsTable" class="grid">
        <tbody id="DemographicsTableBody">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.PK_DemographicsID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor((model => model.Demographic.PK_DemographicsID), new { id = "PK_DemographicsID" })</td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.fk_StatusID_Demographics)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.v_L_Statuses.Single(s => s.PK_StatusID == Model.Demographic.fk_StatusID_Demographics).Status, new { id = "Status" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.fk_GenderID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.v_L_Genders.Single(s => s.PK_GenderID == Model.Demographic.fk_GenderID).Gender, new { id = "Gender" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.HispanicOrLatino)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Demographic.HispanicOrLatino, new { disabled = "disabled", id = "HispanicOrLatino" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfBirth)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfBirth, new { id = "DateOfBirth" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfBirthIncomplete)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfBirthIncomplete, new { disabled = "disabled", id = "DateOfBirthIncomplete" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthMonth)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthMonth, new { id = "BirthMonth" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthDay)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthDay, new { id = "BirthDay" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthYear)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.BirthYear, new { id = "BirthYear" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfDeath)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfDeath, new { id = "DateOfDeath" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfDeathIncomplete)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Demographic.DateOfDeathIncomplete, new { disabled = "disabled", id = "DateOfDeathIncomplete" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathMonth)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathMonth, new { id = "DeathMonth" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathDay)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathDay, new { id = "DeathDay" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathYear)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathYear, new { id = "DeathYear" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.Deceased)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Demographic.Deceased, new { disabled = "disabled", id = "Deceased" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathCertificateNumber)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.DeathCertificateNumber, new { id = "DeathCertificateNumber" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Demographic.Comments)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Demographic.Comments, new { id = "Comments" })</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="DemographicsEdit" style="display:none;">@Html.Partial("_DemographicsEdit", Model)</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDemographicsEdit(pkid) {
        $('#DemographicsEdit').dialog('open');        
    };

    $('#DemographicsEdit').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, title: 'Edit Demographics', modal: true, width: 800, resizable: false, cache: false,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $('#DemographicsEditForm').submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        }
    }).height("auto");

    function SaveDemographics(data, status, xhr) {
        if ($.isArray(data)) { 
            $(function () { ModifyDemographicsTable(data) });
            $('#DemographicsMessage').html("Saved demographics");
        }
        else {
            $('#DemographicsMessage').html(data);
        }
    };

    function ModifyDemographicsTable(data){
        var content = '';
        content += '<tbody id="DemographicsTableBody">';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var holchkd = '';
            var idobchkd = '';
            var idobchkd = '';
            var dcchkd = '';
            if (data[i].HispanicOrLatino == true) { var holchkd = 'checked="checked"'; };
            if (data[i].IncompleteDOB == true) { var idobchkd = 'checked="checked"'; };
            if (data[i].IncompleteDOD == true) { var idodchkd = 'checked="checked"'; };
            if (data[i].Deceased == true) { var dcchkd = 'checked="checked"'; };
            var jsdob = moment(data[i].DateOfBirth).format("l");
            var jsdod = moment(data[i].DateOfDeath).format("l");
            content += '<tr><td style="width:200px">Demographics ID</td><td>' + data[i].PK_DemographicsID + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Status</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Gender</td><td>' + data[i].Gender + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Hispanic Or Latino</td><td><input ' + holchkd + ' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Date of Birth</td><td>' + jsdob + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Incomplete DOB</td><td><input ' + idobchkd + ' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Birth Month</td><td>' + data[i].BirthMonth + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Birth Day</td><td>' + data[i].BirthDay + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Birth Year</td><td>' + data[i].BirthYear + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Date of Death</td><td>' + jsdod + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Incomplete DOD</td><td><input ' + idodchkd + ' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Death Month</td><td>' + data[i].DeathMonth + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Death Day</td><td>' + data[i].DeathDay + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Death Year</td><td>' + data[i].DeathYear + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Deceased</td><td><input ' + dcchkd + ' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Death Certificate Number</td><td>' + data[i].DeathCertificateNumber + '</td></tr>';
            content += '<tr><td>Comments</td><td>' + data[i].Comments + '</td></tr>';
        }
        content += '</tbody>';
        $('#DemographicsTableBody').replaceWith(content);
        
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If your Ajax form submits to a MVC controller action and not to a Web api action, then why don't you directly return a PartialViewResult if saving data is successful.

"OnSuccess event at which time I rebuild the affected table body and then tbody.replaceWith to update the "detail" partial view". you can do this bit within the post action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the following is your Ajax begin form:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("DetailOnePost", "Controller", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "detailOne", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })){
    // Your edit form is here
}
```

and the following is your `Details` partial view, contained within a `<div>` for easy replacement:

```
<div id="detailOne">
    @Html.Partial("PartialName", passmodelforinitialpageload)
</div>
```

Now your post action:

```
public PartialViewResult DetailOnePost(YourModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save your data
        var updatedData = // Retrieve updated details;
        return PartialView("PartialName", updatedData);
    }
    // Handle errors if model state is not valid
}
```

Using this method, you can get rid of `ModifyDemographicsTable` JavaScript function.